# jquery filter via highest number desc

Tags: jquery

Hi all is this possible.

I am looking to setup a jquery filter could i filter the follow list like this.

```
<ul>
<li class="5"> filter</li>
<li class="6"> filter</li>
<li class="1"> filter</li>
<li class="5"> filter</li>
<li class="2"> filter</li>
<li class="4"> filter</li>
<li class="7"> filter</li>
</ul>
```

so after running the filter the outcome would be.

```
<ul>
<li class="7"> filter</li>
<li class="6"> filter</li>
<li class="5"> filter</li>
<li class="4"> filter</li>
<li class="3"> filter</li>
<li class="2"> filter</li>
<li class="1"> filter</li>
</ul>
```

i dont now how to filter by number.

```
<select id="filter" name="filter">
<option value="---">---</option>
<option value="viewed">filter by most viewed</option>
<option value="liked">filter by most liked</option>
</select>

$('#filter').change(function() {

         var val = $(this).val();

         if(val == 'viewed'){

              //dont now what to do here is it possibble

         }


         return false;   
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/02/25/sorting-elements-with-jquery/ for sorting elements with jquery
Or you could just remove all elements beyond `<ul>` (with `$('ul').html('')` and store them in a javascript structure. Then loop through the elements and insert them in the right order. You can get the sort-class-number with the jquery `.class` selector.